# req is not defined - nuxtServerInit

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to set up Firebase Auth with Vuex and Nuxt using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/authentication-with-vuex-and-firebase-f031f799dd98). However if I `console.log(req)` it's `undefined`

In the tutorial the vuex action is:

```
nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
  if (req.session && req.session.authUser) {
     commit(‘SET_USER’, req.session.authUser)
     req.session.cookie=”” + req.session.authUser
  }
 }
```

But no where in the tutorial was it actually defined. Even straight from the docs they have:

```
actions: {
  nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    if (req.session.user) {
      commit('user', req.session.user)
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't find where you initially set `req` or how to access it in the Vuex store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a store/index.js file and define the nuxtServerInit action in there as you have in your second example.

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action